# Retrieving object from scala actor

Tags: scala, actor

I have an intensive task that can distributed but whose end result needs to be accumulated and passed on to another method down the line.

For concreteness, let's say I'm doing word counts for individual files in a large collection of text files.

The version I've worked out so far looks like this:

```
import scala.actors.Actor
import scala.actors.Actor._
import scala.collection.mutable.{ArrayBuffer => mArray}

case object Stop

class Collector(val bin: mArray[(String, Int)], tcount: Int) extends Actor {
  def act() {
    loop {
      receive {
        case (fn: String, val: Int) => {
          // the following "bin" object is what I ultimately need to get back
          bin.append((fn, val))
        }
        case Stop => {
          tcount -= 1
          if(tcount == 0) exit()
        }}}}}

class Processor(col: Collector, flist: Seq[File]) extends Actor {
  def act() {
    for(fn <- flist) {
      val wcount = count words in fn // just a place holder for word counting code
      col ! (fn, wcount)
    }    
    col ! (id, Stop)
  }
}
```

I can think of several homebrewed methods to make the main method wait for collector to finish and then deal with the "bin" object.

But what is the proper scala way to retrieve "bin" above and hand it back to main or what have you?

Answer (score 0):

With an actor, you don't "retrieve" anything as calling actor methods can be dangerous.

Instead, you get the actor to send the answer out. You could add a case for a `GET` object, or in your case you could have it send the `bin` somewhere in the handler for `Stop`.

Answer (score 0):

You could ping an actor using method `!!` to create a future result. The actors receiving the message can fill in the result by using `reply`.

---

However, you save a lot of management work by using executors instead, which are better for *parallelising* tasks (you don't really have a *concurrency* situation here where actors would be particularly useful).

The following is based on Scala 2.10 (forthcoming, you can use 2.10.0-M6 right now), because it contains the improved concurrent framework:

```
import java.io.File
import concurrent._
import java.util.concurrent.Executors

// count words in a file - probably not the best possible way to write this
def wc(f: File): Int = io.Source.fromFile(f).getLines.map(
   _.split(' ').filterNot(_ == "").size).sum

// utility method to get files within a directory (non-recursive!)
def filesInDir(dir: File): Seq[File] = dir.listFiles.toSeq.filter(_.isFile)

// process method which takes a list of files, spawns a word-count for each
// and collects the individual future results into a `Map` whose future is returned
def process(files: Seq[File])(implicit exec: ExecutionContext)
: Future[Seq[(File, Either[Throwable, Int])]] = {
  val futs = files.map { f =>
    // `future` submits the body for asynchronous processing. In order to
    // gracefully handle IO errors, a successful result is wrapped in `Right`,
    // and an exception in `Left`. The caller can decide how to handle errors.
    future {
      f -> (try {
        Right(wc(f))
      } catch {
        case e: Throwable => Left(e)
      })
    }
  }
  // collect all the individual results into one result object.
  // the new single `Future` is only complete after all of the individual futures
  // have completed.
  Future.sequence(futs)
}
```

Example:

```
// use as many threads as there are processor cores
val poolSize = sys.runtime.availableProcessors()

// create a new executor context to be used for spawning
implicit val exec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(
  Executors.newFixedThreadPool(poolSize))

// call the process
val map = process(filesInDir(new File("/my/directory")))

// execute some body when the future is completed
map.onSuccess { case m =>
  m foreach println
}
```

Comment: An alternative to `Either[Throwable, Int]` is `util.Try[Int]` which is also new in Scala 2.10.